# How to determine the optimal number of GPUs for my machine learning script?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

The cluster I am using has 4 NVIDIA's GPUs (P100) per node. I have a tensorflow code that I need to run. It takes many hours to complete and I tried to use all 4 GPUs available on the node. but it looks like it runs slower if I use all 4 GPUs than if I use only 1GPU and I am not sure why... What is the best strategy to determine how many GPUs should I use for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you didn't optimally structure your code for multi-gpu training if you distributed it layer-wise. Generally training speed should scale roughly linearly with number of GPUs.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032721/how-to-force-tensorflow-to-use-all-available-gpus/50032743#50032743) on what options you have to adapt your network to multi-gpu training.